# Using Android TabHost to populate parse data

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-tabhost

I am doing this application  where i need to populate a tabHost list with data from parse.com.

I already have the tabHost working with 2 tabs but i am having trouble calling the information from parse to display into those tabs.

I have already tried to use listView in each tab and used 2 different xml files but nothing is returned.

Any code examples (or examples of populating tabHost) i can use to get the information from parse?

my code so far (MainActivity with CustomAdapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private CustomAdapter urgentTodosAdapter;
private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
private ListView dininglist;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tab.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("CONFIRMED");
    spec1.setIndicator("CONFIRMED");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.layout);
    tab.addTab(spec1);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tab.newTabSpec("PENDING");
    spec2.setIndicator("PENDING");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.layout_two);
    tab.addTab(spec2);

    //Continue to put buttons and call their actions from here
    mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this,  "RestaurantDetail");
    urgentTodosAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    dininglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dining_list_view2);


    dininglist.setAdapter(urgentTodosAdapter);
    urgentTodosAdapter.loadObjects();

}
}

class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>(){

        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query  = new ParseQuery("RestaurantDetail");
          /* query.whereEqualTo("Name", true);*/
            return query;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {

        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout1, null);
    }
    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView)          v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("Logo");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
        todoImage.loadInBackground();
    }

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("Name"));
    return v;
}
}
```

and activity_main.xml file.

```
<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                layout="@layout/layout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_two"
                layout="@layout/layout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></include>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```